# SQL query - get only price changes

Tags: sql, database

I have a SQL database with timestamp product and prices. The price can change many times for a product during the time.

I need to create a report that will show for every product only the changes in the prices for example:

if product price was $4 on Sunday, and $4 on Monday, and 5$ on Tuesday, I want to show:

```
Sunday     $4
Tuesday    $5
```

I wish to skip Monday since it is not relevant because the price was not changed that day.

Thanks for anyone who can send me the SQL query.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Generally, you'll have much better luck / positive responses if you at least show some of your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(price) over (partition by product order by timestamp) as prev_price
      from t
     ) t
where prev_price is null or prev_price <> price;
```

EDIT:

Older versions of SQLite don't support window functions.  One method is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.price
              from t t2
              where t2.product = t.product and
                    t2.timestamp < t.timestamp
              order by timestamp desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_price
      from t
     ) t
where prev_price is null or prev_price <> price;
```

Even with an index on `(product, timestamp, price)`, this is likely to be slower than the previous version.

Comment: thanks for the response  . I am using sqlite . maybe you know the relative syntax in sqlite ?  many thanks

Comment: @mark . . . The syntax in SQLite -- drum roll please -- is `lag()` as described in this answer.  Here is the documentation:  https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html.